# C# Line In Capture

Tags: c#, audio, capture

I wanna record audio from line in (not from a microphone), is it the same way as microphone?

I found some information from the net, but seem all about using microphone.......

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [.NET Voice Recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/) application which uses [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/). And here's a [nice article](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder) about it.